# How to find the most repeated word?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can make the program to print the most repeated word? For now it prints as follow:

> Input:
>   apple banana apple apple
>
> Output:
>
> apple appeared 3 times
>
> banana appeared 1 times

```
int main() {
        string words;
        vector<string> stringHolder;

        while (cin >> words)
        {
            stringHolder.push_back(words);
        }
        sort(stringHolder.begin(), stringHolder.end());

        int vSize = stringHolder.size();
        if (vSize == 0) {
            cout << " no words ";
        }
        int wordCount = 1;
        words = stringHolder[0];
        for (int i = 1; i<vSize; i++) {
            if (words != stringHolder[i]) {
                cout << words << " appeared " << wordCount << " times" << endl;
                wordCount = 0;
                words = stringHolder[i];
            }
            wordCount++;
        }
        cout << words << " appeared " << wordCount << " times" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `std::map<string,int>` to keep track of the word counters.

Comment: `std::map`is indeed the easiest solution. If you are not allowed to use it for a particular reason (homework ...), sort your array `stringHolder`and then count in a linear way with a single `for` loop

Comment: It already has sort function

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How can I add the words to the map with std::map<string,int>. I cant make it to work with map::insert

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `std::map` and a `std::set` for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

// typedef for a "word => count" map
using wordcountmap = std::map<std::string, int>;
// typedefs for making a sorted set
using wordcountpair = std::pair<std::string, int>;
using CompareFunc = bool(*)(const wordcountpair&, const wordcountpair&);
using wordcountset = std::set<wordcountpair, CompareFunc>;

wordcountmap make_wordcountmap(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    wordcountmap wcm;
    // map::operator[] is used to access or
    // insert specified element
    for(const std::string& word : words) {
        // std::string has a std::hash specialization
        // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash
        // calculating the hash for you
        //
        // If "word" does not exist in the map, it will be inserted
        // with a default constructed value, which is 0 for an int.
        ++wcm[word];
    }
    return wcm;
}

wordcountset make_wordcountset(const wordcountmap& wcm) {
    // populate the set using the maps iterators and provide a comparator
    // lambda function that will sort the set in descending order
    wordcountset wcs(
        wcm.begin(),
        wcm.end(),
        [](const wordcountpair& a, const wordcountpair& b) {
            return b.second==a.second ? b.first<a.first : b.second<a.second;
        }
    );
    return wcs;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // put all command line arguments in a string vector
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    // Your "word => count" map
    wordcountmap MyWCM = make_wordcountmap(args);

    // create a set of <word, count> pairs, sorted in count order.
    wordcountset set_of_sorted_words = make_wordcountset(MyWCM);

    // output the number of times the words appeared
    for(const wordcountpair& element : set_of_sorted_words) {
        // element.first  is the "word" in the wordcountpair
        // element.second is the "value" in the wordcountpair

        std::cout << element.second << " " << element.first << "\n";
    }

    if(set_of_sorted_words.size())
        std::cout << "The winner is " << (*set_of_sorted_words.begin()).first << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 apple
1 banana
The winner is apple
```

Comment: Thank you, but visual studio gives the error: "Debug Assertion Failed", Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable.
Also, what does  the stuff in main() do?

Comment: And is there an easier way of doing this? Your code looks too advanced.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out in VS2017 too. The thing in main populates the map (word => count pairs) and uses all those pairs to create a set that is sorted on the count.

It depends on what's considered easy. I'm sure someone can come up with a shorter and/or more effective and/or less advanced way - but I can't right now. I'm just learning more about the STL myself and try to use new things there every day. This was the first time I did something like the above so I'm sure there's a better solution out there.

Comment: It built without complaints in VS2017 and I didn't even have to switch to `/std:C++17` :-)

Comment: I don't see an error? Btw, I edited the answer and tried to split `main` up a little to make it clearer. Edit: Oh, now I see the link

Comment: How strange. It compiles in both debug and release mode for me in VS2017 version 15.8.9. My path to that file is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726` so you should perhaps upgrade.

Comment: I pasted the code on an online compiler but the program just turns off.

Comment: @Jemi When you tested this, did you pass the words as command line arguments? The following expects the words to be command line arguments (and not read usin cin): `std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);`

Comment: Yes. The `std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);` line in main uses the command line arguments to make a vector of all the words.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I passed the words, the compiler just says Compilation successful.

Comment: Sounds very good. Did it run the program too? Which online compiler are you using? (start upgrading VS2017 to the latest version while we speak - it'll probably clear this up right away)

Comment: I just tested this code with Visual Studio 2017 and it worked fine. I put the following in the Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments: `apple banana apple apple` before pressing debug. I also put a breakpoint on the last line of main to get it to not close the window when the program finished.

Comment: @Jemi If you use an online compiler that doesn't support command line arguments, replace the first line in `main` with `std::vector<std::string> args= {"apple", "banana", "apple", "apple"};`